# R substring based on Regular Expression

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a strings like :

```
myString = "2 word1 & 4 word2"
myString = "4 word2"
myString = "2 word1"
```

I would like to get the number before the word1 and the number before word2

```
number1 = 2
number2 = 4
```

How can i do with a regular expression in R

I tried something like this but it only get the first number

```
 gsub("([0-9]+).*", "\\1", myString)
```

Comment: Try [`regmatches(myString, gregexpr("\\b\\d+\\b", myString))`](https://ideone.com/qMMzda).

Comment: thank you for your reply. You are saying to get the 2 numbers in the pattern. The problem with that is that in a string like "4 word2" or "2 word1" i would not know if it comes from "word1" or "word2" . I hope i explained

Comment: Ok, use `str_extract_all(myString, "\\d+(?=\\s*word1)")` to get numbers before `word1` and `str_extract_all(myString, "\\d+(?=\\s*word2)")` to get the results before `word2`.

Comment: Great it works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

You may **extract specific number before a specific string** using a regex with a lookahead:

```
> word1_res <- str_extract_all(myString, "\\d+(?=\\s*word1)")
> word1_res
[[1]]
[1] "2"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "2"
```

The results for `word2` can be retrieved similarly:

```
word2_res <- str_extract_all(myString, "\\d+(?=\\s*word2)")
```

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits...
- `(?=\\s*word2)` - if immediately followed with:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `word2` - a literal `word2` substring.

A base R equivalent is

```
regmatches(myString, gregexpr("\\d+(?=\\s*word1)", myString, perl=TRUE))
regmatches(myString, gregexpr("\\d+(?=\\s*word2)", myString, perl=TRUE))
```

A `sub` almost equivalent solution would be

```
> sub(".*?(\\d+)\\s*word1.*|.*","\\1",myString)
[1] "2" ""  "2"
> sub(".*?(\\d+)\\s*word2.*|.*","\\1",myString)
[1] "4" "4" ""
```

Note that this implies there is only one result per string, while `str_extract_all` will get all occurrences from the string.

**To extract any chunk of 1+ digits as a whole word** using a `stringr` solution with `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(myString, "\\b\\d+\\b")
```

or a base R one with `regmatches`/`gregexpr`:

```
myString <- c("2 word1 & 4 word2", "4 word2", "2 word1")
regmatches(myString, gregexpr("\\b\\d+\\b", myString))
```

See an [online R demo](https://ideone.com/qMMzda). Output:

```
[[1]]
[1] "2" "4"

[[2]]
[1] "4"

[[3]]
[1] "2"
```

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
myString = "2 word1 & 4 word2"
number1 = gsub("([0-9]+).*", "\\1", myString)
myString = "4 word2"
number2 = gsub("([0-9]+).*", "\\1", myString)
myString = "2 word1"
number3 = gsub("([0-9]+).*", "\\1", myString)
print(number1)
print(number2)
print(number3)
```

If you assign 3 times a string to myString, myString will only contain the last one.

Answer (score 0):

This removes each occurrence of a letter or ampersand possibly followed by other non-space characters and then scans in what is left.  The scan also converts them to numeric.  No packages are used.

```
myString <- c("2 word1 & 4 word2", "4 word2", "2 word1")

lapply(myString, function(x) scan(text = gsub("[[:alpha:]&]\\S*", "", x), quiet = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 4

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 2
```